# Is it possible to get another PhD in political science in Germany after getting a PhD in philosophy in Hong Kong

Tags: phd, germany, second-degree, political-science

I am doing a PhD with concentration on continental philosophy in Hong Kong (my MPhil also had the same concentration too), but I am really interested in political theory and political science and often audit relevant courses. I am wondering whether it is possible to get another PhD of political science in Germany, if I focus on empirical political science research or political theory, after finishing my current one, provided my German is fluent enough.

Comment: It may be possible, but perhaps not useful (see other questions on "second phd" on this site). Wouldn't you rather do a postdoc with a project on the crossroads of philosophy and political theory? Goethe University Frankfurt 
comes to mind, but there should be several institutions in this area.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Philosophy is not so competitive in the professorship competition, and the pure philosophy is not something of my original intent... So I wanna change my path...

Comment: @quintus159 Is there not any overlap between these two fields? How far through are you in your PhD? Is there no way to incorporate political science into your thesis?

Comment: @quintus159 Incidentally, if your conclusion is that there is no overlap, and you are certain you want to do a PhD in political science, it would be better to abandon the first PhD (unless you are very close to finished) rather than waste any further time.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks for your comment! It is not very possible to incorporate political science into my thesis. I will finish my first PhD soon, just within one year. Pure philosophy is not very stimulating, but I can completely handle it and it provides me some insights anyway...

Comment: @quintus159 That makes sense, it does sound like it's too late to change your thesis topic. Still, I think henning's advice applies. Even if it takes more time to find a postdoc position which suits you, it will be better than wasting another 3-5 years on a second PhD.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks again! I suppose I won't take much time, since I have had a whole general picture of the second PhD dissertation, but still, time mattes most. I am 26 years old now...

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the "Promotionsordnung" (~Regulations for PhD courses) of the specific universities. As far as I know, it might not be possible to get the same PhD degree twice. They have to be from different fields. It should be possible to get two different PhDs as I know some people who achieved this in Germany.

Comment: Yes, this is something I have thought about. My current PhD is philosophy, having nothing to do with politics. I want to pursue the second one in political science (Politikwissenschaft).

Comment: I know of someone who did PhDs in history and philosophy in Germany, so I'm thinking political science and philosophy would work as well - it certainly depends on the institution's policies.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a PhD and want to go through that process again in Germany, then you can instead try to get a PostDoc position that allows you to write your [habilitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation). Within the German context that would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think it is also quite acceptable!